# backbonejs filter data when passing parameter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying this
try to filter a specific data.

In menu I have a lista I would like when I click in one i get only information about it.

```
 HourView= Backbone.View.extend({       


    initialize: function(){         
        this.template = _.template( $("#HourView").html() );
    },
    render: function () {
        var col = new HourCollection();     

        $.ajax({ //zeptojs
        async: true
        });
        col.fetch({ success: function() {

        }});

        //col.fetch({reset: true});
        $.ajax({ //zeptojs
        async: false
        });           
        col.where({"name": "Gamarra"});


        this.$el.html(this.template({ horarios: col.toJSON()   }));         
        return this;
    }
});
```

[
  {
    "name": "Gamarra",
    "VES": [
      "00:00"
    ],
    "GRAU": [
      "01:00"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Grau",
    "VES": [
      "08:00"
    ],
    "GRAU": [
      "07:00"
    ]
  }
    ]

I am trying this

```
   initialize: function(){  
        this.collection = new HourCollection();         
        this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
        this.collection.fetch({success: function(collection) {
            collection = collection.where({"name": "Gamarra"}); 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(collection))         
        }});            

        this.collection.on("sync", this.render, this);

        this.template = _.template( $("#HourView").html()     );            
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template({ hs: this.collection.toJSON() }));         
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: when I use "where" is because i need to specific part of json and then show in template col.fetch({ success: function() {
       col.where({"nombre": "Gamarra"});
      }}); but it doesn't work... well

Comment: Are there copy'n'paste errors in that code? Does Zepto support `async:true`? Why aren't you using events on `col` to trigger the rendering? Normally you'd instantiate the collection in `initialize`, `col.fetch({ reset: true })`, and listen for the `'reset'` event to trigger `render` (more or less).

Comment: yes but i need this part "[{"nombre":"Gamarra","VES":["00:00"],"GRAU":["01:00"]}]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `where` returns an array (not collection) with the models, so you can use underscore to invoke `toJSON` method on each model so it will look like a `toJSON` but filtered.

```
this.$el.html(this.template({ hs: _.invoke(this.collection.where({"name": "Gamarra"}), 'toJSON') }));
```

The second way is just to use filter on JSON

```
this.$el.html(this.template({ hs: _.where(this.collection.toJSON(), {name: "Gamarra"}) }));
```

Third way is to use `chain` method on collection (btw it doesn't work on your data :( and I don't know why it returns an empty array)

```
this.collection.chain().where({ name: "Gamarra" }).value()
```

Comment: I am trying this parse: function(response) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(response[this.value]))   
   return response[this.value];
  } 

var hourCollection= new HourCollection(value);
it works but view i can't refresh the elements or data..